# Kivy Color Change with Button

Tags: python, colors, kivy

I am currently working on a bit of code using Kivy and Python. I am trying to make it so when you click a button, the button's text changes color.

When I click on the button, however, the color doesn't like I want it to.

Any ideas how this can be fixed? I am just learning Kivy and perhaps the answer is easier than I think. The .py file is below

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color
class TextBubbleSample(Widget):
    bubble = ObjectProperty(None)

class TextBubble(Widget):
        pass

class Talk(Button):
    btn = Button
    def button_press(self):
        btn.bind(on_state = self.on_event)

def on_event(self):
        btn.color = 1,0,0,1

class TextBubbleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TextBubbleSample()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TextBubbleApp().run()




and here is the .kv file

#:kivy 1.0.9

<TextBubbleSample>:
    bubble: text_bubble
    btn: click_here

    TextBubble:
        id: text_bubble
        x: root.x
        center_y: root.center_y

    Talk:
        id: click_here
        x: 10
        center_y: 220
        text: "Talk to me."
        color: 0,0,1,1

<TextBubble>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: 10, 10
            size: 780, 150

    Label:
        color: 0,0,1,1
        font_size: 35  
        center_x: 200
        top: root.top - 200
        text: "I am talking"
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't/can't use the variable `btn` like that. Use `self.bind(on_state=self.on_event)` then `self.color = (1, 0, 0, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to reduce the code length, you don't need to use any id in this case.

There could be an easy alternative to inclement's answer.
In your .py file (Talk class) add.

```
class Talk(Button):
....
def on_release(self):
    self.color = 1,0,0,1
```

and in your .kv file add

```
Talk:
    text: "talk to me"
    ....
    on_release: self.on_release
```

**EDIT:**

you can do it this way too

```
class Singularity(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Singularity,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.b = Button(text = "hello",on_press = self.on_press)
        self.add_widget(self.b)
    def on_press(self,event):
        if event.color == [1,0,0,1]:
            event.color = [0,0,1,1]
        else:
            event.color=[1,0,0,1]
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked! Now I am trying to  change the color back if u hit the button again. I tried a conditional where if self.color is one color and u press the button, it switches to the other color and if self.color is the other color and u press the button, it switches back to the first color, but the conditional isn't working. I know I have my syntax correct and I don't get any error messages. I don't know what's wrong...

Comment: `if self.ids.p.color == [1,0,0,1]: self.ids.p.color = [1,1,0,1] else:
            self.ids.p.color = [1,0,0,1]` **p is id if the button**